# Can't find a process that is writing huge files to my disk

Tags: windows-7, process, service, files

While clearing up my harddrive, I ran into a directory called, c:\logs that had huge files in it.
The first one, called debuglog.txt is 9gb and contains the following data:

```
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
*Killing The Pin 8
*Pin 8 is now dead
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
ProcessWin7_SpeakerPin
```

The second file is PinLog.HTML which is 89gb, which contains:

```
Pin 0x0E4F74F0: Format changed to 44100Hz 16 bits 2 channels  PCM format Interface = Looped  176400 bytes per second
Pin 0x1237A160: Format changed to 44100Hz 16 bits 2 channels  PCM format Interface = Looped  176400 bytes per second
Pin 0x10573600: Format changed to 44100Hz 16 bits 2 channels  PCM format Interface = Looped  176400 bytes per second
```

I've restarted the machine in safe mode - deleted these files, and they keep coming back - slowly but surely - they'll reach the same size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How about using resmon tool(win+r > resmon > ok)...?
In the disk tab, you can find the process which writing to your disk lively...

Answer (score 2):

You can try Process Monitor from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 to check who is modifying this files.

Comment: that what I was about to post, just set the filter to c:\logs and you will see any activity in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this problem too on my computer very recently and was able to fix it with the help of a few friends. For me, these files were being left by the SoundTap audio driver (http://www.nch.com.au/soundtap/), a piece of software bundled with several NCH Software Packages (for me, it came with Debut video Capture Software).

After a while, I discovered a few traits that made this problem a little harder to detect:

1) It won't create the C:\Logs folder on its own, so logging will only start when that folder ends up there (for me, another program created the folder).
2) It will only start logging to PinLog.HTML and debuglog.txt if you try playing audio without an output device attached to your computer.

After I uninstalled Debut and rebooted, the files were no longer being written to and I could safely delete them.